# restore lost commits after push -f

Tags: git, github

I was trying to push to remote repository and I got `Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote`. Then I did `git pull origin master` and it said `Already up-to-date.` Then I tried `git push -f origin master` (dumb!), as a result the last two pushes disappeared from github. Now, when I try `git log`, I can see those two latest commits and their IDs. How can I restore those commits?

Comment: where do you see those latest two commits. are they in origin/master.

Comment: @gregg yes they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `git push -f origin origin/master:master`

this pushes your remote tracking local branch 'origin/master' to the master branch in the origin repository.